# Does compiler sees these uses of else-if as the same thing?

Tags: c, if-statement

Instead of this -

```
if(*condition1*){
    *statement/s*
}
else if(*condition2*){
    *some different statement/s*
}
```

if this is used -

```
if(*condition1*){
        *statement/s*
}
else
    if(*condition2*){
        *some different statement/s*
    }
```

Does the compiler sees both of these as same things, because white-space does not matter in C, and the 2nd `if` gets associated with the `else` statement.

Similarly, for this, do they mean the same?

```
for(*initialization*;*condition*;*increment*)
    ;
```

and this -

```
for(*initialization*;*condition*;*increment*);
```

where ; is a *null statement*.

If yes, then why?

Comment: I get the point now. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes both if and for statements are the same. For C, Space, newline doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt matter at all if you add newlines or whitespaces

Comment: Sir, am I correct that the 1st way of writing `else if` is the same as the 2nd just because of the very reason you gave and while writing, `else if()` is the same as `else \n \t if()` so that it could be concluded that for example, `else i++;` is same as `else \n \t i++;`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Whitespace (apart from its presence at all) truly is insignificant in C. Most C implementations collect whitespace while lexing.

Answer (score 1):

The `else if` conditions are same.
but the for loop is different, because,

```
for(*initialization*;*condition*;*increment*)
                ;
```

here before the ; you can give the statements to execute and it will be executed.
but if you specify the ; without the statements then if the condition is true nothing will be done.

Answer (score 1):

All leading and trailing whitespaces are ignored.